# Can Safari request web pages in my language, regardless of location?

Tags: safari, language

I've been traveling a lot lately, and I notice web servers often serve me pages in a language that matches my current location. If I'm in Greece, I get the page in Greek. If I'm Spain, I get a page in Spanish. I thought there was a way to specify (using an HTTP header) what languages I preferred. Is there a place to enable that? Maybe it is already happening, but web servers are simply ignoring it.