# Is it possible to choose which language to send in Safari and Safari web app requests?

Tags: safari, internationalization, language

I'm seeking a method to select the language preference for webpages while using Safari 17.1 on Sonoma 14.1.

In my specific use case, the OS language is set to English (UK) as the primary language and Spanish as secondary. Consequently, all searches and webpage loads default to English, including the webpages saved as [Web App](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/104996).

I wish to have the ability to choose between sending requests in English or Spanish to load a webpage in the desired language.

This necessity arises from using [Flipboard](https://flipboard.com/), a webpage lacking a language selector, which always loads content in the predefined language. As a result, I receive UK news instead of news from Spain.

Resolving this issue would also address similar instances on other webpages lacking language selectors.

I hope you can assist me!

Related but old and unanswered questions:

- [Can Safari request web pages in my language, regardless of location?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359946/can-safari-request-web-pages-in-my-language-regardless-of-location)
- [MacOS Safari having different app and website language](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/430844/macos-safari-having-different-app-and-website-language)